# Is possible to zoom with mouse in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to zoom in highcharts with mouse, like in Google Earth?

Is there a code to do it?

Comment: The answer you accepted is no longer the best answer, as point out in one of the comments. I have posted the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It looks like this is now possible, see [xendi's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922945/1043380).**

This is the original answer.

---

Nope. Not in the way you describe.

The [Zooming Concepts Page](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/zooming) on Highchart's site says

> With a mouse pointer, the zooming is performed by dragging out a rectangle in the chart. Unlike pinch zooming, the user can't pan the zoomed area, but has to zoom out then in again on a new area.
>
> On touch devices, the user can zoom by pinching in the chart area. On these devices, the user may also move the zoomed area by panning with one finger across the chart.

Those are the only official options you have. There is an active [user voice feature request](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1896011-replace-rectangle-zoom-with-mouse-panning-and-zoom?ref=title), but that was made back in 2011 (4 years ago). I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Your uservoice link now has a link to a working example.

Answer (score 8):

Highcharts mouse wheel zooming can be accomplished by including Highmaps as a module in Highcharts.

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        panning: true
      },
      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        enableButtons: false
      },
      title: {
        text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
          'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Exchange rate'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        area: {
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
              [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
              [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
          },
          marker: {
            radius: 2
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
          states: {
            hover: {
              lineWidth: 1
            }
          },
          threshold: null
        }
      },

      series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: data
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Xendi this will help me a lot :)